# Procedure or function 'SP' expects parameter '@param', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am facing this error from my C# code. Executing the stored procedure in SQL Server is no problem.

> Procedure or function 'SP' expects parameter '@outputparam', which was not supplied.

```cs
public string function1(int param1, string param2)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd;

    cmd = new SqlCommand("SP", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", param2);

    SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@outputparam", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    return cmd.Parameters["@outputparam"].Value.ToString();
}
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP] 
    (@param1 int,
     @param2 nvarchar(50),
     @outputparam nvarchar(20) OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Thats not a returnvalue, thats an output parameter. Change the parameter type.

Comment: And I highly recommend **not** using [`addwithvalue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Tip: You can use an explicit initializer with [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to handle additional options, e.g. `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Filename", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 256, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput, Value = "Foo.bar" } );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these code

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@outputparam", DbType.String);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

change to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@outputparam", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

and

```
return cmd.Get<string>("@outputparam");
```